# I want my files to remain in my git Repo but I don't want anyone to be able to change or submit changes

Tags: git

I have a git repo with a folder that I no longer want any changes to.  I still want the folder there for history.  I've tried using .gitignore but that doesn't ignore already tracked files.  I tried using `git update-index --assume-unchanged my-folder/` but that doesn't seem to allow for wild cards or just directory level ignoring, i.e. files modified under that folder are still showing up as modified (tried it with a * after the slash too).  Any ideas on how to prevent further updates (other than rejecting PRs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

History, in Git, is commits.  You cannot change any existing commit, not at all.  You can make *new* commits.

Each commit has a full snapshot of every file that Git knows about.  The files that Git knows about are those that are in Git's *index*, which Git also calls the *staging area*.  The index is filled in from a commit when you check out that commit.  (So is your working tree.)  From that point on, you manipulate the index copies of each file using `git add` or `git rm`.  The `git add` command makes the index copy match the work-tree copy, replacing whatever was there before (presumably, the copy taken from the commit).

Having manipulated the index to your satisfaction, you then run `git commit`, and Git packages up all the copies of every file that is in the index, into a new commit.

If you remove some files (`git rm`) and commit, the *new* commits will lack the files.  The *existing commits* will continue to have the files, and the history, which is all the commits, is still there.  You just won't see the files in your working tree, because (a) you removed them and (b) Git is checking out the *new* commits that *don't* have the files.

If you check out an *old* commit that *does* have the files, Git will copy those files to Git's index (because that's what `git checkout` does) and to your working tree (because that, too, is what `git checkout` does).  If you then switch from this old commit, that does have the files, to a new commit that does not have the files, Git will *remove* the files from both its index (because `git checkout` needs to do that) *and* your working tree (because that's what `git checkout` does).

So, it's really that simple: you either have the files in new commits, or you don't.

Note that `git push` pushes *commits*, not files.  You either have a commit—in which case you have all the files that are inside that commit—or you don't.  Of course, some people who *receive* the new commits will check them out.  If they had a checkout that had the files, and the new commit doesn't have the files, their `git checkout` (or other operation that results in a checkout, such as merging) will remove the files from *their* index and *their* working tree.

> Any ideas on how to prevent further updates (other than rejecting PRs)?

Rejecting a PR that contains unwanted changes is the reason that we have PRs in the first place.  Otherwise we'd just let anyone `git push` straight into our repositories.

Comment: The answer is correct in that you can't do what I really asked but you will always have the history of those files in the repo.  You can check out an old commit to see deleted files anytime you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @HisDivineShadow,

> I've tried using .gitignore but that doesn't ignore already tracked files.

It does but you have to do some extra work ;)

To ignore an already tracked file, you need to do `git rm --cached <file/path>`.

Best.

Comment: What will happen when I push to my remote repo?

Comment: That will remove the files from the repo, which the question specifcially said is not the desired solution.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger is correct, I don't want the files removed from the repo (thank goodness I didn't run that command).

Comment: Hey I really do not think that your files will be removed. The `cached` option will just remove them from the staging area and not the directory. If you do not believe me then you might as well google it or try it yourself.

Comment: Depends what "removed from teh repo" means to HIsDivineShadow.  It absolutely removes them from the subsequent commit, that's the whole point of the command.

Comment: It just removes it from the cache I suppose. I mean, since it adds it to the `.gitignore`, the file/directory _will_ be removed from the subsequent commits since any changes to it are not tracked.

Comment: So, I tried to test this and when I issued the suggested command it staged my modified file as **deleted**.  Obviously, at that point had I committed it and pushed it the file would have been deleted from my repo.

Comment: It would be great if you could make the slightest effort to check if the file actually got deleted by running a `ls` or `DIR` (if you are on Windows). The `deleted` actually means that the file is now deleted from the cache/staging area/index, not from the file system. It would be better to try things out yourself rather than get swayed by others' opinions (that is an unsaid rule of SO btw).

Comment: It wasn't an opinion it was my actual test.  No, the files wan't deleted, as I said it was marked as deleted in the files that were staged.  That command actually staged the file as **deleted**.  Had I commited it and pushed it, it would have deleted it from my remote repo and that is not what I wanted.